# Atomを起動するとremote-editのエラーが表示される

Tags: atom-editor

Atomを表示すると毎回このようなエラーが表示されるのですが、何か解決法はございますか?

色々試してみたのですが解決に至らずでした。

ご教授いただければ幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Failed to load the remote-edit package
Path must be a string. Received undefined
Show Stack Trace
The error was thrown from the remote-edit package. This issue has already been reported.
View Issue
```

#### 使用環境

Mac OS  10.13.3
Atom    1.25.0
remote-edit@1.9.0

Comment: Atom のバージョンや OS の情報を追記して頂くことは可能ですか？

Comment: また、ターミナルで `apm list --installed --bare` を実行すると Atom にインストールされているパッケージの一覧が出ると思います。その中から `remote-edit` パッケージのバージョンを追記して頂けませんか？

Comment: nelletsuuu様。コメントいただきありがとうございます。質問の方に言われたことを追記しておきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このエラーは、出力によると [remote-edit](https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit) パッケージが原因です。`This issue has already been reported.` とあるように既に報告されているバグであり、エラーと共に現れている "View issue" ボタンを押すと[この issue](https://github.com/sveale/remote-edit/issues/212) として報告されていることが分かります（2018年3月現在未解決です）。また、類似の[この issue](https://github.com/sveale/remote-edit/issues/232) や[この issue](https://github.com/sveale/remote-edit/issues/203) も未解決です。

そこで [remote-edit のリポジトリ](https://github.com/sveale/remote-edit)を見てみると、ここ1年ほどメンテナンスされていないことが分かります。また、他の issue や[フォークたち](https://github.com/urban-1/remote-edit-ni/network)を眺めると、[newinnovations/remote-edit-ni](https://github.com/newinnovations/remote-edit-ni) が活発に開発されているようです。

**提案**: remote-edit の代わりに [remote-edit-ni](https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit-ni) を使うのは如何ですか？

Comment: nekketuuu様、ご回答ありがとうございます。remote-edit-ni を使ってみてまたここに結果を報告させていただきます。ご丁寧なご回答ありがとう誤字ました。